# How can I construct a table header than contains multiple rows in column?

Tags: html, html-table

I would like to construct a table as follows:

[image: Table in excel]

I am trying to construct same table in html but having trouble. Table header needs to be exact. Any help is helpful

Comment: Have you loked at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rowspan` attribute:

```css
th {
  border:1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Permanent Address</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Type of Job</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Start work</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>M/F</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Contract</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Place of Work</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Work Stops</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Birth</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

FYI: there is also a `colspan` attribute if you need to span multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this......

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">#</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Permanent Address</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Type of Job</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Start work</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M/F</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Contract</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Place of Work</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Work Stops</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Birth</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```